# Laravel Connection timeout on getcomposer.org

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install Laravel but i need composer for this. I can't access the getcomposer.org website to download it, because i'm getting an `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` every time i attempt to enter it. I'm not using any proxy. Windows Firewall is off. Pinging to getcomposer.org always returns a request timeout. Are there some other ways I can install Laravel with composer packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a VPN connection to download and install composer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> First, turn your firewall back on before you become part of a botnet.

Second, getcomposer.org works fine from here, so there must be something wrong with your network. However, if you're on linux, you can usually `apt-get install composer` to install it.

If that doesn't work you can grab a copy of the `.phar` file from the getcomposer.org sources on [github](https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/tree/master/web/download). Download the most recent `composer.phar` file. You can use that as `php composer.phar install`.